# Problem editing a vector layer QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have a vector layer which I need to load and edit (add several attribute columns). I am doing this without opening QGIS, so within a Python script. I have the following piece of code for the layer loading:

```
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import ogr

from gdalconst import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *


layer = QgsVectorLayer("/home/usr/Desktop/EligibleAreas_polygons.shp", "EligibleAreas_polygons", "ogr")
if not layer.isValid():
    print "Eligible areas layer failed to load!"
```

When I execute the Python script I get the message that the shapefile could not be loaded. When I try executing the same script from the Python console in QGIS, I get no warning. What could be the problem?

When I execute the next step (creating an attribute column "Land_Area" of doubles) within the Python console:

```
# add new fields
layer.addAttribute(QgsField("LandArea", QVariant.Double))
```

I get **False**. Can someone give me a suggestion on how to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation [Using PyQGIS in custom application](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#using-pyqgis-in-custom-application), you need to add the paths to where QGIS is installed and load its providers before you can use its features and tools:

```
from qgis.core import *

# supply path to where is your qgis installed
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/path/to/qgis/installation", True)

# load providers
QgsApplication.initQgis()
```

And end your script with the following to do a clean up:

```
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```

---

**Edit**:

Few things to note:

- You may need to add the qgis application class reference object `app = QApplication([], True)`
- To add attributes to the shapefile, you need to use `addAttributes()` and not `addAttribute` (not plural). This can only be done by first accessing the layer's `dataProvider()`.

The following script works for me (**note that you will need to change your paths as I use Windows**):

```
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import ogr

from gdalconst import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *

QgsApplication( [], False, home + "/AppData/Local/Temp" )
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C://OSGeo4W64//apps//qgis", True)
app = QApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

layer = QgsVectorLayer("/home/usr/Desktop/EligibleAreas_polygons.shp", "EligibleAreas_polygons", "ogr")
if not layer.isValid():
    print "Eligible areas layer failed to load!"

layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("LandArea",QVariant.Double) ] )

QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```